# how to download files from http link

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have to download files from HTTP web link.

I have created a string like this:

```
string baseURL =  "http://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string content = client.DownloadString(baseURL);
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(content, "*.hdf");
```

I have to download files from folder 278 which has extension of hdf.
but Exception shown like this "Illegal characters in path"
I have to create string and for julian day (here 278) 
I have to modify string and pass it to webclient. 
what is the best way to get the files from http link .

Comment: `content` is not a directory, it's a string.  `Directory.GetFiles` is used with actual directories, where the string parameter is the path to the directory.  Have you tried stepping through your code to see what `content` is?

Comment: Your title makes no sense. But you can't give a *web page* to `Directory.GetFiles()`. It doesn't parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to download the files from the URL:

https://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/opendap/hyrax/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278/

It looks like they provide an XML representation of the files in this directory/catalog:

https://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/opendap/hyrax/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278/catalog.xml

Your best approach to download the files in this catalog would be to...

Step One: Parse the XML to extract the URLs of the images within the catalog.  Here is a useful Stackoverflow post to achieve this first step: [Parsing XML file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901828/parsing-xml-file-using-c).

Step Two: Using the the list of image URLs from step one, go through and download the actual images. Here are some useful posts outlining how to download images using .NET's WebClient.

[Download image from the site in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)

[Using a WebClient to save an image with the appropriate extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543518/using-a-webclient-to-save-an-image-with-the-appropriate-extension)

I hope this provides a general overview on how to achieve your desired functionality.

~Josh

Comment: i will  try to extract the filename from xml. thank you